# удаление столбцов по значению в таблице pandas

Tags: python, pandas

есть датафрейм, хочу удалить столбцы по значению в этом столбце. Как сделать? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого:

```py
df = df.loc[:, (df != 5).all(axis=1)]
```